# Calculate time difference when using time only fields

Tags: datetime, vba

Most of the time I used datetime fields, but for this project it is a requirement to use time fields. The problem is calculations with 2 times not on the same date.

I.E.:

23:00 to 03:00 is 4 hours.

In vba I'm using the following code:

```
Me.TotalTime = IIf(Round(CCur(Nz(DateDiff("n", [startTime], [endTime]) / 60, 0)), 2) < 0, Round(CCur(Nz(DateDiff("n", [startTime], 1) / 60, 0)), 2) + Round(CCur(Nz(DateDiff("n", 0, [endTime]) / 60, 0)), 2), Round(CCur(Nz(DateDiff("n", [startTime], [endTime]) / 60, 0)), 2))
```

Is this the correct way to calculate and or is there an easier method?

Comment: Will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31256021/4717755) help?

Comment: You need a strategy to deal with changes in daylight saving time, or where the the source of the data records in local time and moves from one time zone to another. Since you don't know the date, the problem will have to be solved by the user or device entering the data.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? Any context? When you say time only, you mean disregard any date?

Comment: Have you heard of line breaks or helper variables or functions? You're doing the same calculation four times!

Comment: @PeterT, couldn't get your solution to work.

Comment: @GerardAshton, no need for DST, not in a time zone were it is required.

Comment: @Raystafarian This project is to calculate time worked, where people/machine work in different shifts, not always starting the same time. So the night shift can sometimes start at 23:00 and end at 05:00. So the date should be the next date (not really disregard it). Just for input the require no date to be used, just the time.

Comment: @t3chb0t +1, good catch, but At this point I didn't have any vba code yet, I will update my answer when I get back in the office next week and try to use your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, without the entire procedure, it's difficult for us to review the code. You can take a look in the help center to see the format [of questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If your question gets put "on hold" - don't worry, just update it when you get back to the office and flag it to be re-opened.

Comment: Why are you changing a time difference results (which is in hours) to a currency type `CCur`?

Comment: @PeterT The result should be in decimal and I found this somewhere else and it works for me. i.e. 45 min should be 0.75

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to require worrying about time zones or daylight savings. So if you just want a simple calculation to determine the duration between two times, then a simple function will work:

```
Function DurationDiff(startTime As Double, endTime As Double) As Double
    '--- assumes startTime is the start time in decimal hours (0.0 to 23.99)
    '            endTime   is the ending time in decimal hours
    '    returns duration between the times in decimal hours
    '        (accounts for time crossing midnight)
    If endTime < startTime Then
        '--- midnight crossing!
        endTime = endTime + 24
    End If
    DurationDiff = endTime - startTime
End Function
```

Running a quick test with this function gives you:

```
Sub DurationTest()
    Debug.Print DurationDiff(startTime:=9#, endTime:=17#) & " hours"
    Debug.Print DurationDiff(startTime:=23#, endTime:=3#) & " hours"
    Debug.Print DurationDiff(startTime:=11#, endTime:=15#) & " hours"
    Debug.Print DurationDiff(startTime:=15#, endTime:=3#) & " hours"
End Sub
```

With the output:

> ```
> 8 hours
> 4 hours
> 4 hours
> 12 hours
> ```

I think it then reduces your calculation to nothing more than

```
Me.TotalTime = Nz(DurationDiff([startTime], [endTime]))
```

Comment: I will test it in the office by tuesday, but it seems a solid solution. +1